# Can kinetic energy be extracted from an object moving in vacuum using a gravitational slingshot?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion

Not really sure if physics question or engineering question. If we can apply energy to make an object in space move faster, the reverse should be possible - we should be able to extract energy while causing the object to slow down.

So in theory, if we use rail gun to launch a projectile in space, we should be able to extract energy out of it if we "catch" it with another rail gun.

Considering that, since we can use gravity slingshot to accelerate objects, we should be able to extract MORE energy out of the projectile when we "catch" it. The extra energy would come from the gravity of the celestial body used for the slingshot, which is practically huge. We could use part of this extra energy to redirect the object to the original course, thus creating a stable loop that would allow us to extract vast amount of  energy from the gravity of other planets.

Why wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, it would work. This would effectively be sending a probe to "steal" kinetic energy from another planet and bring it back to earth.

The problem is all in the implementation. Launching something into space is expensive and energy intensive - you'd need a very efficient launch coupled with the ability to bring back a lot of energy to even begin thinking about a net-positive system. You also have the challenge of "catching" the object as it returns to earth moving at several kilometers per second, and efficiently turning that kinetic energy into battery power. On top of that, this system yields large quantities of energy at discrete and irregular intervals that only happen when a slingshot alignment occurs, which makes it a poor choice for continuous power generation for day-to-day life.

Comment: Perhaps you only need to launch it once, and find a trajectory that keeps the projectile moving between earth and any source of kinetic energy?

Comment: Catching it on Earth would be wasteful and inefficient since a lot of kinetic energy would be wasted on reentry. But it can be caught in space more easily. In theory, you should be able to make generation more consistent once you increase the number of projectiles. And since propulsion can be generated using electricity, the projectiles could have their own propulsion systems that allow them to make small corrections to make catching easier.

Comment: @justhalf I imagine that would be quite difficult, gravity assists require a particular configuration of the bodies' relative positions, but that will constant change unless orbits are synchronized in some way.

Comment: @AlexGo More projectiles doesn't really help for irregularity, you can't just perform a slingshot maneuver any time you like - it requires very specific positioning of both planets to get the desired trajectory. You can't launch a projectile every day and get one back every day, as the relative positions change so will the projectile's path and transit time. There may be stretches of time where it's simply not practical to perform a slingshot.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, theoretically it is possible to use the relative motion of other celestial bodies for energy.

Like the many ways it's theoretically possible to harvest energy, it's unlikely this would be better than alternatives of wind, solar, hydro, nuclear energy.